# Editing Asp.Net MVC 5 Scaffolding does not affect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I just fallowed : http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/09/15/customizing-the-asp-net-mvc-5-web-api-2-scaffolding-templates.aspx

and edited `MvcView\Create.cs.t4` but did not affect on the next scaffolding generation.

but changing of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView\Create.cs.t4` affects.